# How to use non-English dimension names in the filter for MySQL data sources in Superset

Tags: python, apache-superset

The non-English dimension name in the filter doesn't seem to be recognized by MySQL because it is enclosed by single quotes (should have been double quotes?) when I checked the raw SQL. Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I upgraded Python to 3.x, it worked out :)